# "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed" exception with lazy load disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-5

Given:

```
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            var result = unitOfWork.Repository.Find<EntityAddress>(a => a.PostalCode == "80001");
            //return View(result.ToList());//NO Exception raised with ToList()
            return View(result);//EXCEPTION RAISED IN VIEW DURING ITERATION
        }            
    }
```

`UnitOfWork` is disposable and handles disposal of my DbContext.  It also disables lazy loading in the constructor:

```
    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Repository = new GenericRepository<MyEntities>(_dbContext);            
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Repository.Dispose();
    }
```

And the `Find<EntityAddress>()` implementation works out to:

`_dbContext.Set<EntityAddress>().Where(predicate)` where predicate is a parameter of type `Expression<Func<EntityAddress, bool>>`

Why do I get a disposal exception even after I disabled lazy loading?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lazy and eager loading have to do with when entities *related* to your query (e.g. navigation properties and collections) are loaded, not when the contents of the query itself are loaded.

The `IQuerable<EntityAddress>` returned from your repository—whether or not you have lazy loading enabled—will not run the query on the server until it's enumerated (whether that's by getting an enumerator in a `foreach` loop, calling [`Enumerable.ToList<TSource>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) on it, or passing it into a call to [`Controller.View`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.108).aspx) for downstream rendering).

The reason you get an exception in this case is because [`Controller.View`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.108).aspx) does not immediately render the view (and therefore does not immediately enumerate the query). All it does is construct an instance of [`ViewResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult(v=vs.108).aspx) that holds onto the model parameter (your query object) until MVC does render the view later on, after you've disposed your context.

If you want to pass query results to a view, you have two options:

1. Extend the life of the database context to the lifetime of the controller
2. Call [`Enumerable.ToList<EntityAddress>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) on the `IQuerable<EntityAddress>` before the database context is disposed, and use the resulting `List<EntityAddress>` instead of the `IQuerable<EntityAddress>`.

Comment: I disposed with the controller.  Works like a champ!  Thanks for the details.

Comment: Is there a way to find out what property or navigation property it is trying to load after dbContext is disposed?

Comment: Great answer. I prefer to call ToList(), as I know I will need the results and then you can just let Dispose look after itself.