# Entity Framework Serialize entity to json with included related entities

Tags: json, entity-framework-6

I have a `User` entity with too many relations to other entities in the system. And I am using AngularJs and want to serialize the `User` entity to json with only the included entities.
Here is my select statement:

```
var users = unc.Users.Include("Profile").ToList();
```

when serializing this to json it will always result into

```
The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed
```

I used to solve this problem by just selecting every column I need in my view like this:

```
var users = unc.Users.Select(x => new { x.Id ,x.Username,Role=x.Role.Name,x.Email,x.Profile.Name,x.UpdatedAt,x.CreatedAt}).ToList();
```

but this is too hard and much code to write. I am looking for the ideal or a better solution.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't get that message if you did a ToList(). Is your serialization code referencing the context?

Comment: @SteveGreene In fact its correct to get that message because When you serialise the entity json serializer will try serialize the all of the properties ownd by that entity so you will get that message.

Comment: Maybe look at the lifetime of your context and extend it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261732/the-operation-cannot-be-completed-because-the-dbcontext-has-been-disposed-exce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v found a decent solution here.
https://efjson.codeplex.com/

This will serialize your entity without including related entities unless you wanted to include those entities. This will avoid entering into circular loops caused by entities calling each other back through reversed attributes.
Also serializing related entities you want will make it easy to serialize an entity and through the JSON back to scripts like AngularJs.

Hope this will make other people happy too :)

Comment: If you already has the entity you want stored in a variable you could just use it like this `return new Json(new { Done = unc.SaveChanges() > 0, User= JsonHelper.ConvertToSimpleObject(userObj, "Profile","Mail.Messages") });`